# Php Ajax Json search and fill the input field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, search

I need to perform a search and save it in input field dynamically. I am new to Ajax.

This is what I have done.
Did a query from database and encoded using json  as below

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Jack"},{"id":"2","name":"Ace"},{"id":"3","name":"Test"}]
```

Now there is a form with an input field for name (note: only existing names from database allowed). When name is being entered, I need to perform a search within Json and get name and display below the input field (exactly how google search shows related search terms) and this name should be clickable once clicked it should populate the input text with that name. And also change value of an hidden input field with respective id.

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="name">
<input id="id" type="hidden" name="id">
```

As I said before only names within the list is allowed, if a non existing name entered hidden element shouldnt have a value or 0 in it.

How can I get it done? And it should be optimised (fast) as it will have to search among a huge data say about 15k-20k names.

Comment: try jquery autocomplete

Comment: The above is correct, [and here's the link to it](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). However, if you're using 15k-20k names, then you should probably use temporary tables to store common search results in, so you don't have to keep querying an entire table over and over.

Comment: I will try that thanks. What do you mean by temporary tables. Isnt that same as querying from tables? When there is an update in the table how will it update temporary tble?

Comment: jquery autocomplete works thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this fiddle i created for your requirement, i used auto complete method

http://jsfiddle.net/X85LT/

```
var src = [{
"label": "Jack",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "label": "back",
        "value": "2"
}, {
    "label": "tera",
        "value": "3"
}, {
    "label": "judo",
        "value": "4"
}];

$('.name').change(function() {
 $('.value').val(0);
});

$(".name").autocomplete({
    source: src,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.value = ui.item.label;
        $('.value').val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

// html

```
<input type="text" class="name" />
<input type="text" class="value" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But I couldnt run it on my site (copied exact code, placed javascript code in head and input field in body), I am using Jquery 1.91 and calendar is working fine. Also I working on CodeIgniter framework if this makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks. Your script worked with few changes sorry i didnt look at it properly.

Comment: Now the last piece of puzzle. How can I pass php variable into javascript. I have saved JSON result in $temp and I tried this inside <script> -  var list = <?php echo $temp; ?> but doesnt work.

Comment: <script>
  $(function() {
   var list = <?php echo $temp.';'; ?>
   $('#name').change(function() {
     $('#id').val(0);
    });
   $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
    source: list,
    select: function (event, ui) {
           event.preventDefault();
           this.value = ui.item.name;
           $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
       }
   });
  });
 </script>

Comment: you are passing it right i think you are missing the quotes  var list = '<?php echo $temp; ?>'; try using this in your script

Comment: the code is fine, the problem here is that your json is getting keys 'name' & 'id'  instead of 'label' & 'value'. try creating the json to have lable & value & it will work fine.

Comment: Yeah true I did that, worked when i used label & value. I saw it is default inside jquery file, I will have to change inside jquery file to make name & id work. well i will stick with label & value for now. Thanks